Using next_permutation on arrays of ints
Given some arrays, I'd like to loop over every possible permutation of these arrays:
Here's a minimal example:
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
//#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Change the first number of the arrays to get a different number of permutations
    // (this is not wanted)
    array<int, 4> A = { 1,0,0,0 };
    array<int, 4> B = { -9,0,0,0 };
    array<int, 4> C = { 3,0,0,0 };
    array<int, 4> temp[3] = { A, B, C };

    int i = 1;
    do {
        cout << "This is the " << i++ << "-th permutation." << endl;
    } while (next_permutation(temp, temp + 3));
    // (it should yield 3! = 6 permutations but only yields 4)

    return 0;
}

However the number of looped permutations seems to be dependent on the starting value of the array (which is not a feature I wish to use in my project).
This is because next_permutation orders it's elements in lexicographical order.
How can I use this function to get all permutations of the given Arrays?
Or do I have to use a different method entirely?
I also know about this answer, but I'd like to avoid sorting my arrays beforehand, since I'm planning to work with a large number of arrays.
Thanks!

You can continue the loop until the initial array content is reached.

You could sort temp before you start generating permutations.

You can use 2 loops with prev_permutation() and next_permutation().

next_permutation doesn't (can't) store the "original" somehow the first time you call it. If you want an arbitrary starting point, save a copy yourself and keep going until you have reached the initial state.

but I'd like to avoid sorting my arrays beforehand, since I'm planning to work with a large number of arrays -- Not tested, but how about calling next_permutation on indices, not the actual values.  The indices would start out as 0,1,2,3, i.e. sorted already.  This is similar to how you would sort items without actually sorting the items (you sort the indexes).

You can do by indirectly mapping the sorted array { 0, 1, 2 }
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
//#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    array<int, 4> A = { 1,0,0,0 };
    array<int, 4> B = { -9,0,0,0 };
    array<int, 4> C = { 3,0,0,0 };
    array<int, 4> temp[3] = { A, B, C };
    int ijk[] = { 0, 1, 2 };

    int i = 1;
    do {
        cout << "This is the " << i++ << "-th permutation." << '\n';
        cout << temp[ijk[0]][0] << "  " << temp[ijk[1]][0] << "  " << temp[ijk[2]][0] << '\n';
    } while (next_permutation(ijk, ijk + 3));
}

Output:
This is the 1-th permutation.
1  -9  3
This is the 2-th permutation.
1  3  -9
This is the 3-th permutation.
-9  1  3
This is the 4-th permutation.
-9  3  1
This is the 5-th permutation.
3  1  -9
This is the 6-th permutation.
3  -9  1


Yes, my comment in the main section describes this.  +1

Ah, sorry! Actually I'd written the code and was just about to post it when the thread got closed. I hope an uptick on your comment is some remuneration!

Thank you both. I think this is the most efficient solution.

This assumes elements of array are unique. With such assumption it is easy to calculate number of permutations and use this number as a loop counter.

@MarekR I think it depends on what your trying to do. If you just want to check each permutation for something, then having a few duplicate permutations isn't a big deal. If you want every possible permutation to count exactly once, then you would need the elements to be unique.

It does seem a bit cheaper to permute integer indices than swap whole arrays around.

Assuming elements are unique (like in the other answer silently assumes) you can just calculate number of iterations:
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <print>

size_t factorial(size_t x)
{
    size_t r = 1;
    while (x > 1)
        r *= x--;
    return r;
}

int main()
try {
    auto A = std::to_array({ 1, 0, 0, 0 });
    auto B = std::to_array({ -9, 0, 0, 0 });
    auto C = std::to_array({ 3, 0, 0, 0 });
    auto temp = std::to_array({ A, B, C });

    const auto n = factorial(temp.size());
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        std::println("This is the {}-th permuation: {::}", i, temp);
        std::next_permutation(temp.begin(), temp.end());
    }

    return 0;
} catch (const std::exception& e) {
    std::print("Exception: {}\n", e.what());
}

https://godbolt.org/z/oW1Yvsrzh
https://godbolt.org/z/MKMMfdf9j
